# BigQuery integration in Firebase repeatedly returns 409

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have a Firebase project set up that continually exports its data to BigQuery (using the standard UI integration) - automatically creating a new `events_intraday_*` table each day.

However, Firebase keeps trying to create the table during the day - even though it's already been created - which results in status code 409.

Could this be a role/permission issue? My Firebase service account in BQ only has the standard `Editor` role.

Comment: Does Firebase create the table and then try to re-create it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The table gets created at the beginning of the day, but it still keeps retrying.

Comment: Status 409 indicates conflict. In this case probably because the table already exists. Can you access the data in the table?

Comment: Yeah, with another account. It's populated correctly. So it seems like the Firebase service account actually writes data into the table _and_ tries to recreate the table, for some reason.

Comment: Where did you see this error message? Can you share the entire message?

Comment: If this happens when you enable the integration, without any code you've written, it might be best to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @rmesteves On the Google Cloud Platform "Activity" tab. The message just says:
"firebase-measurement@system.gserviceaccount.com failed to create events_intraday_20200121".

Comment: @Cethy I agree with Frank, it doesn't seem to be a technical problem from your side. You should call the support

Comment: I contacted support and posted their response as an answer to this thread. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Firebase support and got the following response:

> This is actually a result of some checks to ensure that the dataset is fine and operational. I agree that this makes the activity logs noisy and hard to read though. We're looking into potential solutions to address this, but I don't have any specific details or timelines I can share at this time.

So it appears that it is a known, but harmless, issue.