# Unknown 409 Error on Firebase BigQuery Export

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I'm writing because I'm having trouble understand what could be causing a 409 error. My team set up a Firebase <> BigQuery Link a few weeks ago. The first day of data flowed without any issue. However, every day since then we're getting tons of 409 errors. The error message reads:

`Already exists (HTTP 409): Already Exists: Dataset my-dataset-name`

The reason that this error is concerning to me is that our events table isn't being populated. We have data from the day the integration was created, but no other days.

As far as I'm aware, we didn't set anything up to note which data set the events tables are set up in and I'm unsure how to rectify this error.

Comment: Hello, I would like to share another Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836143/bigquery-integration-in-firebase-repeatedly-returns-409) with the same issue you have described. In that case, it is suggested to reach out to the [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Comment: Updated my question. It's a similar error, but the data isn't being populated into the events table.

Comment: Thanks for updates, but anyway, it's the best way to contact Firebase support in this case.